# Retrieving the statuses of orders on certain dates using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having difficulty creating a Oracle query to report the historical status of orders on certain days (the first of each month over a series of months).  I have searched and searched and have found no one asking a similar question.  It seems like a straighforward problem so hopefully someone can help!  Here is my example:

ORDERS table:

```
    ORDER_NUMBER   STATUS    DATE
    50001000       Created   01-15-2010
    50001000       Released  02-20-2010
    50001000       Completed 02-25-2010
    50001000       Closed    03-10-2010
    50001035       Created   01-20-2010
    50001035       Released  01-25-2010
    50001035       Completed 04-05-2010
    50001035       Closed    05-30-2010
```

So the output I am needing is the status of each order at the beginning of each month.  Something like this:

```
    DATE        ORDER_NUMBER   STATUS
    12-01-2009  
    01-01-2010  
    02-01-2010  50001000       Created   
    02-01-2010  50001035       Released
    03-01-2010  50001000       Completed
    03-01-2010  50001035       Released
    04-01-2010  50001000       Closed
    04-01-2010  50001035       Released
    05-01-2010  50001000       Closed
    05-01-2010  50001035       Completed 
    06-01-2010  50001000       Closed
    06-01-2010  50001035       Closed
    07-01-2010  50001000       Closed
    07-01-2010  50001035       Closed
    ..etc
```

Are there some native keywords that can make this work without lots of joins and subqueries?

Thanks,

Garrett

Comment: Sounds like you can partition by the month/year and then choose the status with the max date for each order.  Perhaps this thread may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561836/oracle-partition-by-keyword

Also, shouldn't status be `Released` on 02-01-2010 for Order `50001035` since it was released on 01-25-2010?

Comment: Yes you are correct I had an error in my example and have now changed it to Released on 02-01-2010.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It took a while, but I think this would be what you're looking for:

```
select to_char(mf.month_first, 'MON-YYYY'), 
       o.order_name,
       o.status
  from (select add_months(to_date('01-DEC-2009'), level-1) month_first
          from dual
       connect by level <= 12) mf
  left outer join orders o
    on trunc(o.status_date, 'MM') <= mf.month_first
 where not exists(
     select 1
       from orders
      where ((trunc(status_date, 'MM') = trunc(o.status_date, 'MM')
              and status_date < o.status_date)
          or (trunc(status_date, 'MM') != trunc(o.status_date, 'MM') 
              and status_date >= o.status_date))
        and trunc(status_date, 'MM') <= mf.month_first
        and order_name = o.order_name)
 order by mf.month_first, o.order_name
```

The above query ensures that if there are two status changes in the same month, the first one is displayed, which is why the comparison between `status_date` and `o.status_date` happens twice, once for when you're in the same month, once for different months...

The `connect by level` subselect allows you to vary the date range by specifying a first date of the month (`01-DEC-2009` in this case) and a duration/length of the report (`12` months).

I hope this is what you were after, though I have to say if you've got lots of orders, this will most likely create lots of rows (especially if an order is completed in March, it'll show up as `Closed` until the end of the report.

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2db21/48) to see it working.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I ran this query on our server and it seems like it times out.  But I also looked into the LEAD ... OVER function (joined on first_day_of_month BETWEEN status_date AND next_status_date; and also looked into MAX ... OVER ... PARTITION BY joined on status_date < first_day_of_month and both are working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understood your sample data but here's the query that may help you - compare your date to the first day of each month:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
 WHERE your_date IN
(
 -- This query will give you the first day of each month --
 Select Add_Months(Trunc(Sysdate,'YEAR'),Level-1) first_day_of_month
   From dual
 Connect By Level <= 12 -- number of months in a year --
)
```

/

Comment: Yes that is good, I like the query being dynamic based on today instead of a hardcoded date.  Thanks!