# How do I know if a ruby on rails application use database partitioning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oracle, partitioning

I would like to disable my rails application's oracle database partitioning, but :

1. I don't know how to tell whether my app is using database partitioning
2. I don't know how to find the place my app use partitioning, since I didn't write most of the application's code myself

Can I just system search the code base for the keyword 'Partition' and look for any result that has the key word partition in raw SQL statement?

How should I go about this?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I have 2 answers below and they seem to understand my question differently

I am confused now as well. I want to disable the partition feature of my Oracle Database (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/partitioning/overview/index.html), does that means I cannot use the 'partition by' keyword ([Oracle "Partition By" Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561836/oracle-partition-by-keyword)) anymore?

Comment: Partitioning is an Oracle licensing option which applies to table structures. If that is what you want to check then @rogercornejo solution is the one you need. This is unrelated to the ability to  `partition by` in window clauses of analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning is done at the schema level declaratively.  Usually, one would not expect the application code to directly need anything specific to use partitioning since it is done at the data definition level.  You can connect to the schema owner account and check the data dictionary views USER_PART_TABLES for partitioned tables owned by the user and USER_PART_INDEXES for the indexes.

Comment: the comment from @APC is 100% correct.  The string searching "solution" is not perfect, but only suggested it as a good start.